# Where I can find .caffemodel file to use for my video analysis project

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, neural-network, object-tracking

I am working on video analysis for shopping mall and involved object tracking concept using OpenCV’s deep neural network module with Caffe models (face detectors).

 I need two sets of files:

1. The **.prototxt file(s)** which define the model architecture (i.e., the layers themselves)
2. The **.caffemodel file** which contains the weights for the actual layers.

These two files required when using models trained using Caffe for deep learning to get more accurate OpenCV face detectors.

However I have found  the **.prototxt files** [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn/face_detector) in the GitHub repo.
But I facing  problem to find **.caffemodel**. I hope to find any solution from here. Thanks

Comment: please be more precise. which model exactly are you looking for ? (the facedetection one ?)

Comment: Yes @berak , Sorry I forgot to mention. Thanks for the reminder.